# Combinatorics - Every ball is unique in its own way

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification, combinations

There are 5 white balls and 7 black balls. In how many ways can we place all the balls in a line assuming every ball is unique in its own way.

My answer is $ \dfrac{12!}{5! \cdot 7!} = 792$

Comment: If they are unique, why not 12!

Comment: The answer of $\binom{12}{5}=\frac{12!}{5!\cdot 7!}$ is the number of ways they can be lined up if each ball were **identical** in every way except possibly color, all white balls being identical to one another and all black balls being identical to one another.  You said however the balls were all *unique*.  If you insisted on writing it as such, you can pick where the whites go and where the blacks go, then arrange the whites in their spots and the blacks in their spots in $\binom{12}{5}\cdot 5!\cdot 7!=\frac{12!}{5!\cdot 7!}\cdot 5!\cdot 7! = 12!$ ways.  Of course, straight is easier.

Comment: If the balls are unique the common color does not change this. You can simply remove any mention of it from the text of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the balls are unique in there way, we have $12$ different objects to arrange in some way in the line. This means, obviously, by definition, $P_12 = 12!$ (permutations combinatorial object = number of ways to choose an ordered set $\sigma$ from a set $S$, containing all the elements of $S$ one time.)

If the balls are not unique, the only distinguishable feature being the colour, the analysis changes radically. Now, we need combinations (2-variable combinatorial object = number of ways to choose a not-ordered subset $s$ from a set $S$ containing exactly $k$ elements.) We have $C_n^k = \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$. We have $12$ positions and $5$ white balls to place in these positions. We have $\binom{12}{5}$ ways to make this choice, and the others will be black.

Your answer looks like you have considered the balls undistinguishable, not unique.